# How to remove noise in a sound with allpassfilter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, fft, noise

Hi all I have a sound with noise.I want to remove that noise how can I remove it?

Original Sound:  [Zamfir-EinsamerHirte](https://clyp.it/5h01obyk)

Noisy Sound: [Zamfir-EinsamerHirte_noisy](https://clyp.it/jpo04y5a)

```
[y4,Fs]=audioread('Zamfir-EinsamerHirte_noisy.ogg');
ffty4=fft(y4);
```

First I analysed the signal

```
shiftedffty4=fftshift(ffty4);
spectrumy41=abs(shiftedffty4);
phaseffty41 = angle(shiftedffty4);

N4=length(spectrumy41);
t4=-Fs/2:Fs/N4:Fs/2-Fs/N4;
spectrumy42=abs(fftshift(ffty4))/N4;
phaseffty42=angle(fftshift(ffty4));
```

Secondly I made a all pass filter with the same length of spectrum and product with fft of noisy sound and made inverse fft and removed imaginary parts and played the sound. The sound still with noise

```
allpassfilter=ones([N4,2]);
allpassfilter(spectrumy42>1e+06)=0;
filteredy4=allpassfilter.*ffty4;
filteredyeni4=ifft(filteredy4);
filteredyy4=real(filteredyeni4);
sound(filteredyy4,Fs);
```

But I couldn't remove noise.The problem is that I don't know how to make zero, the value of noise(location where has noise) in allpassfilter like below:

```
allpassfilter(spectrumy42>1e+06)=0;
```

How can I make it? !!!Any help will be appreciated!!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the clean and noisy audio files. 
First let's analyze a small portion of the audio.

```
n=1024*8; % a small portion of data
w1=1e5;
w2=w1+n-1;

sig_noisy=data_n(w1:w2,1); % noisy audio
sig_clean=data_c(w1:w2,1); % clean audio

figure; hold all
plot(sig_noisy,'b')
plot(sig_clean,'r','LineWidth',2)
ylim([-1.5 1.5])
legend('Noisy','Clean')
```

[image]

As it is seen here, the noisy audio is somehow saturated and
truncated version of clean signal. Truncating a signal cause harmonics 
at larger frequencies. Let's look at the power spectrum
densities of the signals.

```
n=1024*1; % a smaller portion of data
w1=1e5;
w2=w1+n-1;

sig_noisy=data_n(w1:w2,1); % noisy 
sig_clean=data_c(w1:w2,1); % clean  

[psd_noisy, f] = pwelch(sig_noisy);
[psd_clean, ~] = pwelch(sig_clean);

figure; hold all
plot(f/pi,db(psd_noisy),'b')
plot(f/pi,db(psd_clean),'r')
xlabel('Normalized Freq.')
legend('Noisy','Clean')
```

[image]

You see that noisy audio has harmonics plus noise at high frequencies. Well, now if you assume that the characteristics of the noise is not changing through the end of the audio, then you can design a filter with looking at this small portion of the audio. Since you already have noisy and clean signal together, why not use deconvolution method.

For example, if you deconvolve the clean signal with the noisy one, then
you obtain the inverse response of your system (h_inv), which is also the filter coefficients which you can use to filter the noisy signal

(sig_noisy = sig_clean * h).

Here I use Wiener deconvolution method. Also note that this function is not meant to be used for images only, you can also use the deconvolution methods in Matlab with 1D signals.

```
h_inv=deconvwnr(sig_clean,sig_noisy);

figure,plot(h_inv)
legend('h^-^1')
```

[image]

As I said, this is the filter coefficients you need. For example if I filter the noisy signal with h_inv:

```
sig_filtered=conv(sig_noisy,h_inv,'same');
[psd_filtered, ~] = pwelch(sig_filtered);

figure; hold all
plot(f/pi,db(psd_noisy),'b')
plot(f/pi,db(psd_clean),'r')
plot(f/pi,db(psd_filtered),'k')
xlabel('Normalized Freq.')
legend('Noisy','Clean','Filtered')
```

[image]

The filtered signal spectrum is pretty close to the clean signal spectrum. Now that you have the filter coefficients, just filter the whole noisy audio with h_inv and listen to the result.

```
filtered_all=conv(data_n(:,1),h_inv,'same');
sound(filtered_all,48000)
```

You may try other deconvolution methods and see the results. You can also zero the unwanted spectrum in fourier domain and take inverse fourier for clean signal. However, since the signal is too long, you will have to do it in a sliding window. Alternatively, you can design cascaded notch filters to filter each harmonic separately.

I see that there are four stron harmonics. So design four notch filters for each and a low pass filter to filter high-frequency noise.

```
% First notch
fc1=0.0001; bw1=0.05; N=4;
f = fdesign.notch('N,F0,BW',N,fc1,bw1); h = design(f);

% Second notch
fc2=0.21; bw2=0.2;
f = fdesign.notch('N,F0,BW',N,fc2,bw2); h2 = design(f);

% Third notch
fc3=0.41; bw3=0.2;
f = fdesign.notch('N,F0,BW',N,fc3,bw3); h3 = design(f);

% Fourth notch
fc4=0.58; bw4=0.2;
f = fdesign.notch('N,F0,BW',N,fc4,bw4); h4 = design(f);

% A Final lowpass filter
f = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',0.6,0.65,1,30);  h5 = design(f);

% Cascade the filters
hd = dfilt.cascade(h, h2, h3, h4, h5);

% See the filter characterisctic
ff=fvtool(hd,'Color','white');

% Now we can filter our 
sig_filtered2 = filter(hd,sig_noisy);
[psd_filtered2,f] = pwelch(sig_filtered2);

figure; hold all
plot(f/pi,db(psd_noisy),'b');
plot(f/pi,db(psd_clean),'r');
plot(f/pi,db(psd_filtered2),'k');
xlabel('Normalized Freq.')
legend('Noisy','Clean','Filtered')
```

[image]

[image]

Now you can filter the whole audio

```
filtered_all2 = filter(hd,data_n(:,1));
sound(filtered_all2,48000)
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: thanks. yes I have both, clean and noisy sound but I will use clean sound for checking, not to clean noisy sound.And Our propose is not to use any inner filter of matlab. we must make a all pass filter and make the part of noise zero then dot product with noisy sound to remove noise in freq. domain. So I just need to find noise location so I will make the last code I asked in question.
This is a homework so I need to clean this way.

Comment: Then you can use the second approach I suggested (cascaded notch filters). If you want to do it with FFT, you can do it in some small portion of data, because the signal itself is too long.